# Upgrade to EE2 - Playa content not displaying

Tags: playa, ee2-upgrades

I just upgraded a large site from EE1 to 2.6.1 and to Playa 4.4.3. The site was previously using Solspace's Related Entries, and Playa seemed to have converted these successfully - the related entries appear in the Playa field in the Edit Entry forms. However, they do not appear in the front-end templates.

I assumed this was my syntax error, but in fact any newly created entries do display their Playa content in the template as expected, and if I re-save an old entry, its converted Playa content also displays fine.

```
{exp:playa:children field="news_field_group_related_entries"}
 <li><a href="...">{title}</a></li>
 {/exp:playa:children}
```

and

```
{news_field_group_related_entries limit="10"}
<li><a href="..."> {title}</a></li>      
{/news_field_group_related_entries}
```

both work.

There are several thousand entries so not realy practical to update each one manually. And it's a busy live site so I don't want to try anything too radical. What can I do?

Comment: Have a look at the `exp_playa_relationships` table in your database. Any entries where `parent_field_id` is empty or 0? Pick out an entry that has children but is not displaying on the front-end - does it have the appropriate number of entries under that `parent_entry_id` in `exp_playa_relationships`?

Comment: The table looks OK - `parent_field_id` is as expected and `child_entry_id` values look right too - I checked a couple, and they do belong to the expected child entries, though those entries are not displaying on the front end.

Comment: Prompting me to look at the database was helpful as it occurred to me that I could try using a query: `{exp:query sql="SELECT child_entry_id FROM exp_playa_relationships WHERE parent_entry_id = '{embed:entry}' ORDER BY child_entry_id DESC"} ...` and this seems to do the job. It would be good to get an official fix for this though, if P&T are lurking?

Comment: Zack, for an offical fix or an official observation on what has gone wrong, you'll have to shot us an email to support@pixelandtonic.com, preferrably with some CP access :)